# Understanding an identity for least squares regression line gradient

Tags: summation, least-squares, weighted-least-squares

In section 2.2 of [this paper](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/%7Egelman/research/unpublished/thirds4.pdf), Gelman and Park present the following identity for the gradient of the least squares line through a set of 2D points:

> ...we recall a simple algebraic identity that expresses the least-squares regression of $y$ on $x$ as a weighted average of all pairwise comparisons:
>
> $$\begin{align}
> \hat\beta^{ls}&=\frac{\sum_i(y_i-\bar y)(x_i-\bar x)}{\sum_i(x_i-\bar x)^2}\\\\
> &=\frac{\sum_{i,\,j}(y_i-y_j)(x_i-x_j)}{\sum_{i,\,j}(x_i-x_j)^2}\\\\
> &=\frac{\sum_{i,\,j}\frac{y_i-y_j}{x_i-x_j}(x_i-x_j)^2}{\sum_{i,\,j}(x_i-x_j)^2}\end{align}$$

In the first line, which is a basic least squares result, the series are iterating over all the points. In the second and third lines the series are iterating over all *pairs* of points.

It feels like I might be missing something obvious, but how do we go from the first line to the second?

Comment: $\bar{x}$ is the average of the $x$ values, and implicitly sums over all of the values.

Comment: @BrianBorchers In other words: 
$\hat\beta^{ls}=\frac{\sum_i\left(y_i-\frac 1 n \sum_j y_j\right)\left(x_i-\frac 1 n\sum_j x_j\right)}{\sum_i\left(x_i-\frac 1 n\sum_j x_j\right)^2}$... and then?

Comment: @BrianBorchers Actually - that was great hint. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Rewrite the numerator

\begin{equation}
\sum_i(y_i-\bar y)(x_i-\bar x)
=
\sum_i(y_i-\frac{1}{n}\sum_j y_j)(x_i-\frac{1}{n}\sum_j x_j)
\end{equation}
that is

\begin{equation}
\sum_i(y_i-\bar y)(x_i-\bar x)
=
\sum_i(\sum_j \frac{1}{n} y_i-\frac{1}{n}\sum_j y_j)(\sum_j \frac{1}{n}x_i-\frac{1}{n}\sum_j x_j)
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
\sum_i(y_i-\bar y)(x_i-\bar x)
=
\sum_i\sum_j( \frac{1}{n} y_i-\frac{1}{n} y_j)(\frac{1}{n}x_i-\frac{1}{n} x_j)
=
\frac{1}{n}
\sum_{i,\,j}(y_i-y_j)(x_i-x_j)
\end{equation}

---

### Rewrite the denominator

\begin{equation}
 \sum_i(x_i-\bar x)^2
 =
 \sum_i(x_i-\bar x)(x_i-\bar x)
 =
 \sum_i(x_i-\frac{1}{n}\sum_j x_j )(x_i-\frac{1}{n}\sum_j x_j )
\end{equation}
that is
\begin{equation}
 \sum_i(x_i-\bar x)^2
 =
 \sum_i\sum_j(\frac{1}{n}x_i-\frac{1}{n}x_j )(\frac{1}{n}x_i-\frac{1}{n} x_j )
 =
 \frac{1}{n}
 \sum_i\sum_j(x_i-x_j )^2
\end{equation}

---

### Replace now

So
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\sum_i(y_i-\bar y)(x_i-\bar x)}{\sum_i(x_i-\bar x)^2}
 =
 \frac{\frac{1}{n}
\sum_{i,\,j}(y_i-y_j)(x_i-x_j)}{\frac{1}{n}
 \sum_i\sum_j(x_i-x_j )^2}
=
 \frac{\sum_{i,\,j}(y_i-y_j)(x_i-x_j)}{\sum_{i,\,j}(x_i-x_j)^2}
\end{equation}